# Data Recovery Options for Unmountable Macbook Pro Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, data-recovery

My daughter's 2012 MBP would not load the OS (Lion I believe). She took it the the Apple store and they told her it was a failing hard drive but her AppleCare had just expired. I was able to boot the drive into recovery mode, but the main volume was not recognized. I tried to target boot with an iMac but the drive would not mount.

I put a new SSD in the MBP and it runs great. I put the old drive in a USB case and tried to mount it on an iMac, I was prompted for the password, entered it, but the drive wouldn't mount.

At this point I'm trying to see what my options are for data recovery. I thought I might try something myself before sending it out, but don't understand how programs like Data Rescue & EaseUs would work when the drive won't even mount?

Comment: If there is important irreplaceable data, e.g. pictures you just can't afford to lose, that you truly want to recover then I'd strongly recommend sending the HDD to [Kroll Ontrack](https://www.krollontrack.com). Depending on just how the HDD is failing, e.g. say the actuator arm and or heads are malfunctioning, they have the ability to physically remove the platters and put them in a working case where the rest of the mechanical components are functioning properly and thus enable the maximum amount of data recovery.

Comment: Seconded the above comment. Data recovery programs **can** do a good job, but operating the drive *as is* could result in further data loss. it depends on how valuable the data is. if it would be nice but not necessary to get the data I would say buy a data recovery program. If it is **VITAL** that the data not be lost, send to off to a data recovery specialist. I haven't done that in years, but it was not inexpensive then. Likely that has not changed.